# How to change the default CSV separator?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I´m trying to read a csv file separate with ;.

Code:

```
import csv
with open('Ingresos_e_eCPM_por_fecha_y_cliente.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print ', '.join(row)
```

I have this csv data:

```
21/12/2017;En;229.620;18.508;8,06%;14,56;0,79
22/12/2017;En;204.042;48.526;23,78%;43,98;0,91
23/12/2017;En;102.613;20.223;19,71%;17,86;0,88
24/12/2017;En;90.962;19.186;21,09%;14,26;0,74
25/12/2017;En;60.189;12.654;21,02%;11,58;0,92
```

The problem is when I try to read with my python code, It shows me these:

```
21/12/2017;En;229.620;18.508;8, 06%;14, 56;0, 79
22/12/2017;En;204.042;48.526;23, 78%;43, 98;0, 91
23/12/2017;En;102.613;20.223;19, 71%;17, 86;0, 88
24/12/2017;En;90.962;19.186;21, 09%;14, 26;0, 74
25/12/2017;En;60.189;12.654;21, 02%;11, 58;0, 92
```

I need the data in the same way as the csv!

Comment: Your input file uses both ';' and ','? Also, csv stands for comma separated value which you don't have.

Comment: ... did you try setting the delimiter to a semicolon? Your reader is using the default comma delimiter .

Comment: You don't have a csv file- you have a semicolon separated value file. Try`csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')` perhaps?

Comment: done! Thanks @pault

Comment: This question almost surely is dupe, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Why aren't you using pandas with `sep=';'`?

Answer (score 2):

If you read the documentation you will see that you can specify a [`Dialect.delimiter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter) telling the csv `module` what character is used to seperate fields.

```
csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)
```

> The other optional `fmtparams` keyword arguments can be given to
>   override individual formatting parameters in the current dialect.

In your case:

```
spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
```

Answer (score 2):

You should adjust the comma-seperated-value (csv) file delimiter to a semicolon `delimiter=';'`:

```
import csv 
with open('Ingresos_e_eCPM_por_fecha_y_cliente.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print ', '.join(row)
```

An alternative would be to use one of the provided dialects (the usual culprit for csv sperated by semicolon is excel):

```
import csv 
with open('Ingresos_e_eCPM_por_fecha_y_cliente.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print ', '.join(row)
```